# show $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}, z\mapsto \frac{z}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}}$ is infinitely many times real differentiable.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have this function $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{D}, z\mapsto \frac{z}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}}$, with $\mathbb{D}$ the open unit disc $\{z\in\mathbb{C}| |z|<1\}$. I already showed that it has an inverse $f^{-1}:z\mapsto \frac{z}{\sqrt{1-|z|^2}}$. Now I have to show these functions are both infinitely often real differentiable. I tried to differentiate $f$ once, but I already failed since I find it hard to differentiate $|z|^2$. Can someone help?

Comment: One has $\mathrm{d}_z|\cdot|^2\cdot h=2\textrm{Re}(\overline{z}h)$, more generally, $\mathrm{d}_z|\cdot|^p\cdot h=p|z|^{p-2}\textrm{Re}(\overline{z}h)$.

Comment: Look at it in real coordinates. And use the fact that compositions, products, quotients etc. of smooth functions are smooth.

Comment: @DanielFischer but $z$ is not smooth right?

Comment: It is. That one's even holomorphic.

Comment: @DanielFischer okay so I can say that since $z$ is smooth and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+|z|^2}}$ is a fraction and therefore smooth, $f$ is smooth and thus infinitely many times real differentiable?

Answer (score 0):

If
$$f(x,y)=p(x,y)\bigl(1+x^2+y^2)^{-n-1/2}$$
for some $n\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq0}$, whereby $p$ denotes some complex valued polynomial in the variables $x$ and $y$, then $f$ is continuous on all of ${\mathbb R}^2$. Using the usual rules for computing partial derivatives it is easily checked that ${\partial f\over\partial x}$ and ${\partial f\over\partial y}$ are functions of the same type, whereby $n$ is increased by $1$.